# `var is None` vs `var == None`

Tags: python, coding-style

Why do people prefer `var is None` over `var == None` when `is` can be used on few objects only?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The authoritative reason is "Because [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says so":

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

Note: It's not merely "better practice", as **equality** vs. **identity** are distinct semantical constructs.

---

In `python`, testing implicit 'truthiness' is generally preferred over comparison to an explicit value.

Choose

```
if somevar:
    ...
```

over

```
if somevar is True:
    ...
```

over

```
if somevar == True:
    ...
```

---

Advantages

- emphasizing the explicit desire to compare identity to a builtin
- inability to break the comparison by defining `__eq__` on arbitrary objects

---

Answer (score 1):

actually, it isn't about programming style, `is` and `==` are very different:

the `is` operator checks if the two items reference the same object

the `==` operator checks if the objects that the two items reference are the identicle

for example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,]
l2 = l         # make ir reference the object that l references
l3 = l[:]      # copy it so reference identicle objects

l is l2 # same objects
True

l == l2 # identical objects
True

l is l3 # same objects
False

l == l3 # identical object
True
```

when you slice the list, you're copying it and creating another object identical to it; when you say `l2 = l` you're making a new variable that references the same object

source: Learning Python 5th edition by Mark Lutz; part II: Types and Operations, chapter 6: The Dynamic Typing Interlude pp. 180-184

Comment: The question is about the specific case where you compare with `None`.

Comment: But it answers it: “x is None” is true if x is the same object as the global “None” object, not just an object that is equal to the global “None” object.

Answer (score -3):

A key thing to bear in mind about nearly every language is that "`==` is stupid."  It is "a literal binary test for 'equality.'"  Operators such as `is` are, *per contra,* specifically designed to be aware of the underlying runtime type system, including things like inheritance and so-forth.  While the compiler may accept the use of `==`, it is not the right operator to use in this setting.

Comment: In Python `==` is not a literal binary test for equality. Types can customize their comparison behavior by implementing rich comparison methods like __lt__(); for types that don't, `==` is based on the identity of the objects. Never the literal binary value.

`is` is not aware of the underlying runtime type system. It simply compares object identity.

Comment: Your statement is entirely correct ***for Python.***  Other languages may differ – and may differ *considerably.*  Therefore, I would politely argue that you should be as precise as possible in whatever language you are now using: `==` and `is` are distinct *contextual* cases which should be kept *"visibly* distinct." *"Class-specific customization of operators"* can lead to very-considerable confusion  in practice, and should be approached with caution. (Because: "the source-code in front of the coder's face does not instantly suggest what is actually going on.")

Comment: The question is tagged `python`. In Python, `==` is used for equality, `id` is used for identity, and binary equality test is a thing that doesn't exist. What other languages do is entirely irrelevant in answers to this question.

Comment: Just remember: If you use _any_ language, you better learn what things like ==, ===, is, equals etc. mean _exactly_ or you will run into bad surprises.